# Duplicating PHP lines

Tags: php, scripting

I have a problem, first off, I have a variable $num_newlines that changes to the amount of lines a files has. Then what I want to do is duplicate a line to one less than what $num_newlines equals. The line is:

```
$tweetcpitems->post('statuses/update', array('status' => wordFilter("The item $array[1] has been released on Club Penguin.")));
```

What I want to do next is that for each duplicate line I want the array number to change, for example:

```
$tweetcpitems->post('statuses/update', array('status' => wordFilter("The item *$array[1]* has been released on Club Penguin.")));
```

Then the second line to be like:

```
$tweetcpitems->post('statuses/update', array('status' => wordFilter("The item *$array[2]* has been released on Club Penguin.")));
```

Then the third line to have $array[3] and so on. The main problem is that I don't want to have to manually add the lines of code and change the numbers because the variable $num_newlines is always changing. Any help would be **HIGHLY** appreciated as I've kept on researching on how to do this, but found nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for ($i=0; $i<($numlines - 1); $i++) {
    $tweetcpitems->post('statuses/update', array('status' => wordFilter("The item $array[$i] has been released on Club Penguin.")));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use a for loop

```
for($i=1,$i<=$lines,$i++)
{
// ............'status' => wordFilter("The item $array[$i] has been released on Club Penguin.")));
}
```